# Retrieving data from mongo db in MEAN Stack app

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mean-stack

Am learning MEAN stack and for the same in my local mongo db I have created a collection 'eduLevel' with some documents as follows:

```
> db.eduLevel.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : "G001", "name" : "Graduate" }
{ "_id" : "M001", "name" : "Masters" }
{ "_id" : "P001", "name" : "P.hd" }
```

And I have created a model for the same in my MEAN App as:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const eduSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('eduLevel', eduSchema);
```

when am executing following line of code, am getting edu as null in response (in console log am getting the id value),

```
app.get('/edu/:id', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  let edu = await Edu.findById(req.params.id);
  console.log(edu);
  res.status(200).json({
    edu: edu.name
  })
});
```

what is it that am doing wrong here?

Comment: can you include ```Edu.findById``` function code here. I think you have forgotten to add ```async``` in the function definition.

Comment: Can you show your request ?

Comment: Edu is the imported model which I have written, I have imported it like this:const Edu = require('./models/edu'); and findById is the mongoose method for finding a document by id, I haven't overridden it

Comment: @DheerajKumar this is how I am making the request from my Angular service to retrieve the data (if that's what you are asking): getEdu() {
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/edu/G001').subscribe(console.log)
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your code you are missing callback for findbyId.

```
 app.get('/edu/:id', async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.params.id);
      await Edu.findById(req.params.id, function (err, data) {
        if(err){
        console.log(err);
        es.status(500).send(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        res.status(200).json({
        data: data.name
        })
      });

    });
```

Comment: nope this didn't work, and I have already added the keyword await so why do I need a callback again? But by changing the model name to 'edu' in edu.js file and creating a collection by the name edus resolved my issue.:) :)

Comment: Happy for ya ! :)